# Enable syntax highlighting and code completion in CDF player?

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, wolfram-player

Try coding on iPad has fun, I downloaded the free app [`Wolfram Player`](https://apps.apple.com/cn/app/wolfram-player/id1059014516) in App Store and found it can interact with Wolfram notebooks `*.nb` or `*.cdf` files locally but cannot change its code.

Then I used `Manipulate` and `InputField` to construct a simple Wolfram Language interpreter.（using App-in purchase）

```
Manipulate[
 ReleaseHold@WL, 
 {WL, "Type the WL here!", InputField[#, Hold@Expression] &},
 Initialization -> Needs["Benchmarking`"]]
(* app version 12.1.1 works fine *)
```

[image]

However this code has some problems:

1. Some codes output blank field such as `GeoGraphics[]`(in app System Context) and `` Benchmarking`Benchmark[] ``
2. It’s too simple to have no syntax highlighting, code completion and error throwing mechanism.

Could we improve the code and enjoy the coding on iPad?

Or Is there text editors app or offline services that supports Wolfram Language syntax highlighting on iPad? (such connect this app with iSh app that support Linux)

***interesting things:***

It's a small pocket Mathematica, only 317MB on iPad rather than 11GB desktop version almost without degradation of function numbers.

```
UnitConvert[
 Total[FileSize /@ 
   Select[FileNames[All, $InstallationDirectory, Infinity], 
    FileType[#] == File &]], "MB"]
Names["System`*"]//Length
```

The efficiency on iPad Pro 2020 (12.9-inch) even **faster** than MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017)!  (same version 12.1.1)

It seems that *iPad Pro is a real productivity tool*! (But `` Benchmarking`Benchmark[] `` couldn't work for further tests)

```
AbsoluteTiming[CellularAutomaton[110, {{1}, 0}, 10000];]
(* Mac 2.29s iPad 0.51s, four times faster *)

Graph[Table[i -> Mod[i^2, 74], {i, 1000000}]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* Mac 1.82s iPad 1.34s *)

AbsoluteTiming[
 Table[Thread[{r, Nest[r # (1 - #) &, Range[0, 1, 0.01], 10000]}], {r,
 0, 4, 0.01}];]
(* Mac 5.30s iPad 2.06s, two times faster *)

AbsoluteTiming@Total[Prime[Range[PrimePi[10^7]]]]
(* Mac 1.34s iPad 1.02s *)

newt = Compile[{{z, _Complex}, {n, _Integer}}, Module[{zn = z},
Do[zn = (2 zn + 1/zn^2)/3, {n}]; 
If[Re[zn] > 0, 1, If[Im[zn] > 0, 2, 3]]]];
 Timing[Hash@
   Table[newt[x + I y, 25], {y, -1, 1, 2./999}, {x, -1, 1, 2./999}]]
(* Mac 3.30s iPad 2.75s *)

c = Compile[{{x}}, x^2 + Sin[x^2], CompilationTarget -> "C"];
{c, c[10.5]}
(* wow, the app support C language natively and links it back in for execution *)
```

The Wolfram Player has a location in Files, then we can `Export` the files to other apps or PCs for further processes.
[image]

Welcome any comments!

This command list all the system information,cool! `SystemInformation[]`

Comment: Well there is Wolfram Cloud, which seems to be quite powerful for this kind of tasks. It however requires an account and I do not know what the free/basic plan/account is capable of but the commercial account attached to my Mathematica License seems quite capable.

Comment: @N0va yeah, but the wolfram cloud is not running in the local, so it has limitations on running time and memory usage.  And running dynamic programs get stuck

Comment: There are some bugs in Wolfram Cloud too. Love your way to insert code in Player

Comment: I do not know about iPad version but CDF FreePlayer does not allow arbitrary input fields. If they work it is a bug and if you use them then it is against the license though I found it only because I knew it: https://www.wolfram.com/cdf/adopting-cdf/cdf-and-mathematica-comparison.html.en

Comment: @Kuba Oh No...  But if there is `Dynamic` and `InputField` functions in CDF FreePlayer, it can accept WL inputs.

Comment: @partida All InputFields work like InputField[..., Number] in desktop FreePlayer. (unless enterprise signed). The table above says that numerical input is allowed.

Comment: My hope is that if the player already works on an a14 chip in the ipad, Wolfram will have a short turn around time to release MMA on the new arm macbooks coming out at the end of the year and i can finally upgrade my 2013mbp

Comment: @morbo ARM-based MMA looks great

Comment: You may already know this, but the tests in `Benchmark[]` can be found in `AddOns/Packages/Benchmarking/Benchmarking.m` if you want to run them manually.

Comment: You cannot make a CDF Wolfram Player that can run arbitrary code through an inputfield. There are deliberate limitations on that. You need an Enterprise license on your Mathematica to lift these restrictions, IIRC.

Comment: @Kuba If purchase the dynamic features in this App, then  it not against the license

Comment: @partida is it a Player Pro equivalent for mac?

Comment: @Kuba I haven't downloaded player pro for mac, I don’t know

Comment: 你现在在哪里上班来着？方便来我司看看不？可以的话加下q了解一下？

Comment: @yode 好呀 在合肥 1298856981